# Wifi network connection fails after a while

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp

By "fails", I mean that it's still *connected* to the network, but I cannot access anything. The Internet does not work, I can't access the router page and I can't even ping any device on the network.

I have a Lenovo T61 with Windows XP. The wireless router is a Belkin N. I haven't noticed any cause for this (e.g. heavy downloading etc.) except that it usually happens around 9AM (weird, I know and probably irrelevant). Also, restarting the wireless connection does not work and restarting the computer works most of the time.

The network is fine since I have other wireless devices on it. I've only tried a wired connection to the router when the wifi failed once, and it might have worked.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Went through the router page. No IPs or MAC addresses are blocked (Belkin N can block devices during some time of the day).

Comment: The fact you can't connect to it at certain times is very strange. When this occurs, can other devices still connect at the same time, this will suggest if the fault is PC side or Router side

Comment: I believe it's the PC side since other wireless devices on the network (netbook, smartphone) work without a problem.

Comment: During this period of no wireless, what happens if you plug it in via ethernet?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is just that you have to live with using this router. Here is the quotation from one of reviews:

> Stability - Well, as noted by the first four paragraphs of this
>   review, stability is the one category the Belkin Wireless N fails
>   miserably in (that and tech support anyway). Aside from the trouble of
>   setting up the wireless to work correctly, however, there is also the
>   problem of random dropped connections, which is fortunately mitigated
>   by the router's ability to reset quickly, but it is still a problem
>   nonetheless.

[Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CNCQO2) is the source.

All I can suggest for now is to update the firmware on router

Comment: Do you think these dropped connections would affect one device and not another on the network?

Comment: I really think that this is possible

Answer (score 1):

Use a program like INSSIDER (metageek.com) to look at the wifi in your area and consider switching channels, sometimes networks all get jammed up on one channel.  Also, remember that things like vacuums, microwaves, phones, UFO's, etc. can all interfere with Wi-fi.  Perhaps someone gets up and microwaves their oatmeal everyday at 9:00AM.